# Find extreme values for $f(x,y)=\sin^2(x)+\sin^2(y)$ over the constraint: $(x^2-y^2)^3+(x^2-y^2)=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

Find extreme values for $f(x,y)=\sin^2(x)+\sin^2(y)$ over the constraint: $(x^2-y^2)^3+(x^2-y^2)=0$.

Im free to solve this problem with any method. So far I tried to solve this one using the method I understand better which is Lagrangian multipliers, this way for: $\nabla f=  \lambda \nabla g$ where:

$$g(x,y)=(x^2-y^2)^3+(x^2-y^2).$$

Im pretty sure there is some shorter way to do this because proceeding the way I said I got pretty nightmarish equation systems to solve. I mean,

$$\nabla f= 2(\sin(x))\cos(x)i+ 2(\sin(y))\cos(y)j= \sin(2x)i+\cos(2y)j.$$

But

$$\nabla g =g_{x}i+g_{y}j=[6x^5-12x^3y^2+6xy^4+2x]i+ [-6x^4y+12x^2y^3-6y^5-2y]j.$$

So finding the values for $x,y$ and $\lambda$ such $\nabla f=  \lambda \nabla g$ is satisfied becomes a nightmare as I said before. I would really aprecciate any help to understand and finish this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Start by the equation you haven't mentioned yet.

Comment: Hint: solve $z^3+z=0$

Comment: in typing this, your sen should be \sin and your cos should be \cos

Comment: Already corrected! @WillJagy

Comment: You mean g(x,y,z) ?@SaucyO'Path

Comment: @Cos your constraint can be simplified to $(x^2-y^2)=0$ since $(x^2-y^2)^3+(x^2-y^2)=((x^2-y^2)^2+1)(x^2-y^2)=0$. The first part is never $0.$ See also Empy2's hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$(x^2-y^2)^3+(x^2-y^2)=0 \iff (x^2-y^2)=0 \iff y=\pm x.$

Note that $f(x,-x)=f(x,x).$  Thus we have to find extreme values of $f(x,x)=2\sin^2 x.$

I am sure you can finish from here.

Comment: Thanks to formulate the problem in an easier way! Now I wil give a try! :) @user376343

Comment: You're welcome :)